# Does Microsoft Surface support Flash websites?

Tags: flash, windows-8, windows-rt

I've searched Google but have not found a clear answer.

Will my or my work's Flash site / application run on Microsoft Surface tablet?

Comment: It might not *technically* be Windows 8, but .. it should give some more focus. I didn't want to tag as `WinRT` (stupid failed billion-dollar marketing and overloaded terms).

Comment: PST Thanks. I agree. I wasn't sure WinRT stands for. My assumption is it's Windows running on mobile CPU's or MS Surface OS. I should probably do search on what it is? :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that IE on Microsoft surface will have a list of approved sites where flash is supported, and this list is maintained by Microsoft!

Check [this post:](http://news.cnet.com/8301-10805_3-57537730-75/top-10-biggest-drawbacks-of-windows-rt/)

> 1. Flash only works on approved sites. Think you'll be able to watch
>      all those Flash-based videos using your new RT computer? Well, think
>      again. Flash will only run on sites approved by Microsoft. Lucky for
>      you, CNET is one of them.

Maybe it is time you redo your site with HTML5 instead, as many are stepping away from flash and also Adobe are dropping flash support from some platforms.

Comment: Our project has been in development for 2 1/2 years and HTML5 does not support all the features we need (video camera, video streaming, etc). Adobe dropping support is inconsiderate and self centered to all companies and individuals who invested in them.

Comment: You are welcome. Yeah I know it sucks but Adobe already knew that flash is dying and they don't want to spend money supporting systems that won't give them enough revenue back. Anyway, are you sure HTML5 doesn't support streaming and cameras? Because I thought one of the main goals of HTML5 was to replace flash as a media delivery mechanism!

Comment: I'm not sure that *they* think Flash is dying (because now they are pushing Flash for gaming) but yeah they are screwing over their loyal customers and other businesses that rely on them. I would love for HTML5 to work but it does not support video camera and video streaming support in all browsers at the time of this writing and last I checked. Let's say they did though we still need to support a few browser versions back in time (maybe 3 year old browsers).

Comment: Good luck with what you are doing. Regarding the surface, there should be a way you can get microsoft to test and approve your site then add it to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [this post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/SurfaceSoftware/thread/7ecdf9b3-cf5f-4c94-8644-7ebeb3cf6f14) on Microsoft's TechNet, which says:

> Surface does not consume or utilize flash. You can create your own handler to do this but it is not usually the best user experience. Flash only understands clicks and not the surface enabled controls. If you write your own events to transfer the input you can handle this but then you’re running flash from within a windows application.

This was posted by a Microsoft representative, so I assume it's accurate. I guess the answer is: "Not really."