# Html flash code won't work for FireFox

Tags: php, html, flash

That's the code generated by Adobe CS5 Flash Professional when you publish:

```
<div id="flashContent">
        <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="100%" height="100%" id="website" align="middle">
            <param name="movie" value="website.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#CF9" />
            <param name="play" value="true" />
            <param name="loop" value="true" />
            <param name="wmode" value="window" />
            <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
            <param name="menu" value="true" />
            <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
            <param name="salign" value="t" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <param name="FlashVars" value="'.$flashvars.'" />
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="website.swf" width="100%" height="100%">
                <param name="movie" value="website.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#CF9" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="t" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <param name="FlashVars" value="'.$flashvars.'" />
            <!--<![endif]-->
                <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                </a>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
    </div>
```

There is also my flashvars... But won't work for FireFox. So I'd made a detection by $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] and a custom code with the code inside [if !IE] to make it work.

I don't know these kind of tags, so the question is: is this code wrong or FireFox doesn't recognize it at all?

Comment: What does show? Does FF tell you there is a plugin missing?

Comment: worth mentioning that it won't work on an iPhone/iPad, since they don't support Flash at all, nor on MS Surface tablets since they limit flash support to pre-approved sites ([ref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366683/does-microsoft-surface-support-flash-websites)).

Comment: [I recommend the satay method](http://alistapart.com/article/flashsatay), it's a lot less verbose.

Comment: FF shows nothing, nor some specific error message. But I'd follow the signs... I don't know about iPhone, but flash is for desktops. I'll take a look at that satay method, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice for including Flash in HTML is to use SWFObject - it is a javascript library for embedding flash content (more recent versions of Flash Pro use it i believe).

It works in all browsers and has handy features like checking flash player version and providing alternative content when flash player not installed.

The code is available here with full instructions: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

I have also written a blog post on using it here: http://blog.leeburrows.com/2011/07/javascript-for-flashers-swfobject/